# Measuring voltage between two points...wirelessly?

Tags: wireless, voltage-measurement

I want to measure voltage between points A and B. Let's assume that there's some obstruction/difficulty in simply attaching cables between those points. Is it possible to measure the voltage wirelessly somehow?

I had an idea of a device that measures voltage at some point with reference to an on-board stable potential S. Let's say two such devices are attached to points A and B:
Device 1 measures voltage between A and S
Device 2 measures voltage between B and S
Measurements are then transmitted wirelessly to a server. Is it possible to "substitute for S" and recover voltage between A and B?

Thank you in advance for your answers :-)

Comment: Depends on the exact requirements... How much measurement precision are you trying to achieve? How closely must the location "A" and "B" voltage references "S" agree? How rapidly are measurements needed? How closely must the measurements be synchronized? What is the approximate voltage range of A and B? Is there some kind of harsh operating environment? Industrial? Medical? Automotive? What is the cost budget? Could you not simply use a handheld DVM to measure each point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as an "on-board stable potential" with reference to the outside world. All voltages are relative - a voltage is a potential difference - so in order to measure the voltage between two points, you either need to compare them directly, or you need a common reference potential to compare each to.

In a small area you might use neutral or an earth ground as your common potential, but these can vary over larger areas.

The obvious question is, if you don't have a potential you can use as a reference for both measurements, then how will the resulting measurement be meaningful or useful at all?

Answer (score 0):

Well, to measure the current wirelessly, one can utilize a clamp ampermeter. Although, details are not provided, I suppose this is not what you are looking for; as you can come to the voltage if you know the resistance in between and current is not divided on it's way between the points.